# phpunit test in laravel doesn't show the real sesion table

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

When I use the browser, I see that the values in the session are correct because I use them to display data.

However, when I display a session table in phpunit, it only shows the value for one key:

[image: session array screenshot]

Controller:

```
 public function add(Book $book)
    {
        $cart = session('cart');
        Book::addToCart($cart, $book);

        return back();
    }

Model: 
     public static function addToCart($cart, Book $book)
    {
        if (!$cart) {
            self::createCart($book);
        } else {
            self::updateCart($cart, $book);
        }
    }


    private static function createCart(Book $book)
    {
        $cart = [
            $book->id => [
                'id' => $book->id,
                'title' => $book->title,
                'quantity' => 1,
                'image' => $book->image,
                'price' => $book->price
            ]
        ];
        session(['cart' => $cart]);
    }

    private static function updateCart($cart, Book $book)
    {
        if(isset($cart[$book->id])){
            $cart[$book->id]['quantity']++;
            session(['cart' => $cart]);
        } else {
            $cart[$book->id] = [
                'id' => $book->id,
                'title' => $book->title,
                'quantity' => 1,
                'image' => $book->image,
                'price' => $book->price
            ];
            session(['cart' => $cart]);
        }
    }
```

for example simple test (result in img)

```
use WithoutMiddleware;

/** @test */
public function cart_is_created()
{
    $book = Book::first();

    $this->get('/add-to-cart/' . $book)
        ->assertSessionHas('cart');
    dd(session()->all());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you show us your tests? When using phpunit with Laravel there's some traits/classes that make sure you connect to a test database instead. This database is usually emptied before testing, which might explain you findings.